# How do I combine 2 boolean observables into a single boolean observable if either are true?

Tags: rxjs

To make my specific condition as easy as possible I have the following observables.

```
const a = of(true);
const b = of(true);
```

I am looking to determine that if either or both of these are true then return an observable of true but if both are false, return an observable of false.

```
if (a || b) ? true : false;
```

I seem to be tripping over how to combine them correctly, I was using `combineLatest` to get an array.

```
combineLatest([
    a,
    b,
])

// [true, true]
```

I think that https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/some.html is what I need but that seems long gone and searching for "some" isn't amazing.

```
combineLatest([
    a,
    b,
]).pipe(
   some(x => x === true)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) to produce single observable based on multiple source observables:

```js
const myBool$ = combineLatest([a$, b$]).pipe(
    map(([a, b]) => a || b)
);
```

Your combined observable will emit an array of values whenever any of the sources emit (*note it won't emit for the first time until each source emits at least once*).  You can then use the [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator to transform the emitted array into your single boolean.

The code above will emit the boolean value whenever any source emits.  However, it may not be desirable to receive emissions if the resultant value hasn't changes (ex: if a and b are both `true`, then `b` changes to `false`, the result is still `true`).

We can prevent emitting the same result by using [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged):

```js
const myBool$ = combineLatest([a$, b$]).pipe(
    map(([a, b]) => a || b),
    distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

Comment: Thanks BizzyBob! I edited 30 seconds before you replied, it is good to get your confirmation on `combineLatest` tho.  However,  if  `a: true, b: false` then it emits twice. One for true, one for false.  But I was looking for it to emit only once.

Comment: I was actually already working on adding that... : - )   Answer UPDATED!