# How to return true if either one observables returns true of unknown amount of observables

Tags: rxjs

I have a function in which there could be a number of unknown observables defined:

```
class Foo {

  show$(multipleObservables$: Observable<boolean>[]): void {
    // ...
  }
}
```

And in the locations where I use this class, the number of observables vary. It could be 1, but it could also be three:

```
const observableOne$ = of(false);
const observableTwo$ = of(true);
const observableThree$ = of(false);

const observables$ = [observableOne$, observableTwo$, observableThree$];

Foo.show$(observables$);
```

How can I write the show$ function to return true when any observable is true, or false when they are all false?

I've [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237635/how-do-i-combine-2-boolean-observables-into-a-single-boolean-observable-if-eithe), but that assumes you already know the number of observables. Is there a way that you can create this function without knowing the observables on forehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to depend on whether the source Observables are going to complete or not. If you're going to use just `of()` you could do it like this:

```
show$(multipleObservables$: Observable<boolean>[]) {
  return forkJoin(multipleObservables$)
    .pipe(
      map((results: boolean[]) => results.some(Boolean)),
    );
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's not just 'of()'. Posted a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534356/subscribe-to-multiple-subject-providers

Answer (score 0):

You can use combineLatest for any number of observables in this scenario:

```
const observables$ = [of(false), of(true), of(false)];

const myBool$ = combineLatest(observables$).pipe(result => result.some(x => x));
```